# Create a line plot with marker colour based on a different column

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a simple data frame with 3 columns: Date, Value (continuous) and Category (3 classes A, B and C). I want to plot Date on the x axis, Value on the Y axis as a line plot, but with a marker on each point displaying a different colour based on the Category column three classes?

I am using Python, looked around around but haven't found anything just for that. Any thoughts?

Comment: i would plot the lines and marker separately via `Axes.plot` and `Axes.scatter`, respectively

Comment: have a look at `seaborn` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by Paul H, `plot` the points as a line and a `scatter`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dr = pd.date_range('01-01-2020', '01-15-2020', freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':dr,
                   'Value':np.random.rand(len(dr)),
                   'Category':np.random.choice(['A','B','C'], size=15)})

colors = {'A':'red', 'B':'blue', 'C':'green'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['Value'], color='black')
ax.scatter(df['Date'], df['Value'], c=df['Category'].map(colors), zorder=3)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=5))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, that worked like magic. Thanks for sharing the code!

Comment: @HectorArroyoGzlez, you're welcome, please accept if the answer is suitable : )